# Can I Customize the LayOver of Google Maps sattelite-view (Google Maps API)? Remove Overlay

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, customization

did anyone ever try to style the Fonts/Lines/etc of the GoogleMaps-Sattelite View? I know about SnazzyMaps and other Google Maps customizer, but they dont have a sattelite style option?

Thanks for helping out,

Julia

UPDATE:
I figured out to get rid of all the labels on the hyprid/sattelite view.
Using: 
var mapStyle = [

{
  featureType: "all",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
]

and use it when creating the map:

function createMap(standort) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(
        mapElem, 
        {
            zoom: 12,
            minZoom: 3,
            mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
            mapTypeControl: false,
            styles: mapStyle,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            }
        }
    );

I just have one more question, does anyone know how I get rid of the street/Border-Overlay--> [Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw356.jpg)